# What happens to energy changes in non-reversible processes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Take internal energy for example:
$$dU\leq TdS-PdV$$
Firstly, I would like to make clear that the following question/argument relies on the following statement being correct: the left hand side of the above equation represents the change in internal energy of the system and the right hand side represents the work done on the system by the surroundings. Please clarify if that is correct.

The two equations, above, are in fact inequalities where it only becomes an equality when the system is at equilibrium (when changes are reversible). However, when  the system is not in equilibrium the inequality implies that the work done on the system by the surroundings is greater than the internal energy gained by the system; how can this be? Where does the energy difference between the energy put in and the energy gained by the system go?

Secondly, at a constant $S$ and $V$, spontaneous changes occur only when $dU \leq 0$. What's going on here? Is it as simple as: the system must lose internal energy in a spontaneous change or does it mean that work must be done on/by the system in a different way (eg. electrical work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta U = q + w$ and $dU = dq + dw$

This is the [first law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics).  It is not an inequality.

$dU\leq TdS-PdV$ is correct when there is only PV work. It is incorrect when there is other work such as electrical or gravitational.

> the right hand side represents the work done on the system by the surroundings. Please clarify if that is correct.

The PdV term alone represents the reversible work, the TdS term represents reversible heat

> Secondly, at a constant $S$ and $V$, spontaneous changes occur only when $dU \leq 0$. What's going on here? Is it as simple as: the system must lose internal energy in a spontaneous change or does it mean that work must be done on/by the system in a different way (eg. electrical work)?

the system must lose internal energy in a spontaneous change

Comment: The equality assumes equilibrium  though doesn't it? This is certainly the case for G: $dG\leq VdP-SdT$. What happens in that instance?

Comment: $\Delta U = q + w$ and $dU = dq + dw$ do not assume equilibrium.

Comment: If you write $dU\leq TdS-PdV$ as an equality, that assumes quasistatic (near equilibrium) and only PV work.

Comment: Sorry, I see now I think. However, $dU \leq TdS-PdV$ is a valid inequality isn't it? Assuming equality at equilibrium?

Comment: I have edited my question now - I see my error.

Comment: as an inequality, $dU\leq TdS-PdV$ is valid even without assuming equilibrium, but assuming only PV work.  As an equality, it assumes quasistatic (near equilibrium) and only PV work.

Comment: I understand that but the right hand side still represents energy put into the system and the left is the change in energy of the system right? So where does the energy go if he two sides of the equation are not equal (i.e. when the process is irreversible)

Comment: Perhaps my question is better put in another way. When at a constant P and T $dG\leq w_e$ indicating that the change in gibbs free energy at a constant P and T is the electrical work done. In a non-reversible process, where the loss of Gibbs free energy is greater in magnitude (the electrical work is also negative) then where does the rest of the energy go?

Comment: (response to second to last comment) the right hand side no longer represents energy put into the system, because TdS no longer represents q

Comment: Why? It has units of energy.

Comment: when the process in irreversible, S can increase without any change in U.

Comment: Okay. May you please address the second point in my question.

Comment: yes, I added to my answer

Comment: Thank you. How does the system lose the energy? As heat?